# Difference of sys.path

Tags: python

The following two python runs don't print the same output. Does anybody know why there is a difference? Thanks.

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ cat main.py 
import sys
print("\n".join(sys.path))
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))' | head -n 1

$ python3 ./main.py | head -n 1
/private/tmp
```

Comment: What is the difference on your system?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The difference is clear in the question - the first one prints nothing, the second one prints `/private/tmp`.

Comment: No difference. The commands were run on the same system.

Comment: Yes. But be specific on which answer on that page. Not all answers are relevant.

Comment: Obviously, @kaya3. However, then the obvious answer is that the reason is that there are different values in `sys.path`, which doesn't help. However, describing the difference would have lead to the question this one here duplicates. ;)

Comment: The answer here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Answer (score 0):

Sys does not only print your current path, It slso prints your libs and their corresponding paths.

Run the below code and it will give you an understanding of what you're doing and what you need to do in order to get current working directory.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

import os
print(os.getcwd())
```